# Most Efficient way to organize database with data for seperate organizations

Tags: database, sqlite

So this is more of a theoretical question. I am fairly new to databases, but here is my issue. I have a website which has users which will be divided up into different organizations. These organizations have nothing to do with each other, would I want to store them all in separate databases? different tables? or store them in the same databases and tables with columns to specify which organization they are a part of? Currently using SQLite but willing to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options.

1#:
Hold everthing in one database, add additional fields to your tables and some logic to deceide who has access to what. Cons: That will be a mess, Pros: you will have less issues when transferring data from one organization to another.

2#:
Create a fresh new database for each organization. Cons: More data transfer needed when transferring data between organizations, Pros: Far less logic and data mess. :)

I would prefer the second option. But there is a lot of software out there which was build with the first option in mind.

Comment: I cannot think of an instance where I would ever need data to be transferred between organizations, so I will go with option number 2. Should I have another database/table which would keep track of which DB belongs to which org?

Comment: Don't forget to plan to duplicate (triplicate, quadruplicate, ...) the stuff common to all customer databases; for example you might have tables of countries, addresses, validation tables, *etc* or to plan to write the code to ensure that the copies always agree.